# How does the ThreadPool decide which type of thread to use for a work item

Tags: .net, multithreading, threadpool

There are two types of threads that the ThreadPool utilizes - worker and I/O threads.

According to [this answer](https://That%27s%20because%20%22the%22%20thread%20pool%20is%20actually%20two%20thread%20pools:%20there%27s%20worker%20threads%20(that%20execute%20queued%20work)%20and%20there%27s%20I/O%20threads%20(that%20enlist%20in%20the%20I/O%20completion%20port%20and%20handle%20low-level%20I/O%20completion).) from Stephen Cleary:

> ... "the" thread pool is actually two thread pools: there's worker threads (that execute queued work) and there's I/O threads (that enlist in the I/O completion port and handle low-level I/O completion).

From what I was able to read in the source/debug BCL with DnSpy there is actually just one queue. (correct me if I am wrong).

So my questions how does the call to

```
 ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(callback)
```

internally decide which type of thread to use for the WaitCallback delegate?

Comment: There are two thread pools, a worker pool for CPU heavy tasks (worker threads)  and another I/O pool for time consuming tasks like writing to a file or calling third party software. Runtime you .net creates only worker threads, so you don't see multiple thread pools unless you are doing timeconsuming tasks.

Comment: You can see in the source code that it has a separate callback for IOCP https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/9d9b2505c6cb03b3682f3e9a8b6bf6cfd67d2926/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/WindowsThreadPool.cs#L191 which are system-managed threads

Comment: I/O completions are handled internally in the CLR.  That QUWI call will always be treated as a worker since it wasn't initiated by an async I/O request (say, ReadAsync()).  You can't change that decision.

Comment: @HansPassant yeah, I tested a bit more and seems the case. 
So would it be fair to assume that certain BCL APIs / language constructs will always be treated as worker and other will always as IO completions?

Comment: That is accurate.  It is not supposed to matter, it always does the Right Thing.  Hard to guess why you asked this question.

Comment: @HansPassant was trying to create an example that makes the workings of the IO threads visible and distinguishable from that of a worker thread. I guess it's not possible and should just accept them as black box implementation details.